# Book about a woman who travels 100 years back in time when she looks in the mirror

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel, young-adult

I read this book in high school, and I thought it was called *Kate's Story*,  but there's another book called that here in recent years.   I could be wrong.

This woman is with a man and another couple.  They are in this cottage house just for a getaway weekend.  There's a big stand up mirror, and this woman looks in it as she gets ready to go out.  She travels back in time 100 years, and that's all I remember.  She travels back and forth, and one time her friends find her on the bed.

I think it was written in the '70s.  I bought it through a book club in school.  Those papers that had lots of books to choose from.  You could buy like five and get one free.  It was a paperback.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. I know you said you think this was written in the '70s, but can you tell us the approximate year in which you read it? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: [Mirror of Danger](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3197997-mirror-of-danger), published in the UK as _Come Back, Lucy_ has a mirror that takes the protagonist 100 years back in time, though it doesn't look as if it's set in a holiday cottage. The date fits since it was published in 1974.

Comment: You can see a list of SFF novels with "Kate" in the title [here](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&O_1=contains&TERM_1=kate&C=AND&USE_2=title_ttype&O_2=exact&TERM_2=NOVEL&USE_3=title_title&O_3=exact&TERM_3=&USE_4=title_title&O_4=exact&TERM_4=&USE_5=title_title&O_5=exact&TERM_5=&USE_6=title_title&O_6=exact&TERM_6=&USE_7=title_title&O_7=exact&TERM_7=&USE_8=title_title&O_8=exact&TERM_8=&USE_9=title_title&O_9=exact&TERM_9=&USE_10=title_title&O_10=exact&TERM_10=&ORDERBY=title_copyright&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title).